# Difference between fabric-tools and fabric-ca-tools images

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

what is the purpose of fabric-tools and fabric-ca-tools and its diferences

Below mentioned the docker images of Hyperledger Fabric

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hyperledger/fabric-tools       1.4.3               18ed4db0cd57        7 days ago          1.55GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       latest              18ed4db0cd57        7 days ago          1.55GB
hyperledger/fabric-ca-tools    latest              591e9bb05cad        11 months ago       1.55GB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fabric-tools**:

It is a helper container when we go for automation of HLF network creation we can use this container for generating configuration stuff it will have all tools available

- cryptogen
- configtxgen
- configtxlator etc

Note: It doesnt have **fabric-ca-client** in order to talk to fabric-ca

**fabric-ca-tools**:

It is a helper container when we go for automation of HLF network creation we can use this container for generating configuration stuff it will have all tools available

- cryptogen
- configtxgen
- configtxlator etc

Note: It **does** have **fabric-ca-client** in order to talk to fabric-ca

Comment: Could you also share a link to the documentation? I couldn't find anything in their docs about these images.

Comment: It has been quite long time and fabric team decided to deprecate both images, https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v2.4.4