# Use of fabric-tools image in production

Tags: containers, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, production

I've been doing some research but with no luck so here goes: Is the fabric-tools container image appropriate for production block-chain networks?

P.S. I know I don't have any code errors or a more technical question but I don't know where else to ask this. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our responses to the production requirements, we have not setup Fabric Tools image in production.

The reason was, for a tls enabled network, for this tools image to actually serve the purpose, it needs the tls certificate of each node to be mounted into this container - which I think might be questionable in a production scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/4f1e0931eb233b82c0a53658bbba8a9debf61d2b/images/tools/Dockerfile) from the official fabric Github. In this line you see the tools, which are build inside the fabric-tools image.

Like in this post mentioned [Difference between fabric-tools and fabric-ca-tools images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766212/8141874) it includes the tools:

configtxgen configtxlator cryptogen discover idemixgen osnadmin peer

The fabric-tools Container is a helper Container, which you can use to make things easier. For example creating a channel, joining it etc.
You can do the operations without it.
In production you would use f.e. a CA instead of creating the **crypto-config** artifacts with the cryptogen tool.
Also the fabric-tools container is usually used to mount the whole channel-artifacts folder and the crypto-config folder. This would not be very practical for productive use. You might have to make a modification depending on the intended use.